# Object vs. Dictionary: how to organise a data tree?

Tags: python, object, resources, dictionary, tree

I am programming some kind of simulation with its data organised in a tree. The main object is `World` which holds a bunch of methods and a list of `City` objects. Each `City` object in turn has a bunch of methods and a list of `Population` objects. `Population` objects have no method of their own, they merely hold attributes.

My question regards the latter `Population` objects, which I can either derive from `object` or create as dictionaries. What is the most efficient way to organise these?

Here are few cases which illustrate my hesitation:

**Saving the Data**
I need to be able to save and load the simulation, for which purpose I use the [built-in json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) (I want the data to be human readable). Because of the program is organised in a tree, saving data at each level can be cumbersome. In this case, the population is best kept as a dictionary appended to a `population` list as an attribute of a `City` instance. This way, saving is a mere matter of passing the `City` instance's `__dict__` into Json.

**Using the Data**
If I want to manipulate the population data, it is easier as a class instance than as a dictionary. Not only is the syntax simple, but I can also enjoy introspection features better while coding.

**Performance**
I am not sure, finally, as to what is the most efficient in terms of resources. An object and a dictionary have little difference in the end, since each object has a `__dict__` attribute, which can be used to access all its attributes. If i run my simulation with large numbers of `City` and `Population` objects, what will be using the less resources: objects or dictionaries?

So again, what is the most efficient way to organise data in a tree? Are dictionaries or objects preferable? Or is there any secret to organising the data trees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not a hybrid `dict`/`object`?

```
class Population(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self[key]
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value
```

Now you can easily access known names via attributes (`foo.bar`), while still having the `dict` functionality to easily access unknown names, iterate over them, etc. without the clunky `getattr`/`setattr` syntax.

If you want to always initialize them with particular fields, you can add an `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, starting=0, birthrate=100, imrate=10, emrate=10, deathrate=100):
     self.update(n=starting, b=birthrate, i=imrate, e=emrate, d=deathrate)
```

Comment: `namedtuple` is, sadly, immutable.

Comment: and now you have a javascript like object, with unecessary two way access feature. "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.".

Comment: Thanks. I really like this one because it's a healthier dictionary. When it comes to saving and loading however, although the saving part is made easy because it is readable, it remains cumbersome when loading because i'd have to reload each json string as a hybrid dict again.

Comment: There are plenty of places where Python has more than one way to do something.  :-)  I can see where it would be somewhat of a pain to have to go through what you've parsed from JSON and convert all the dicts though.

Answer (score 2):

As you've seen yourself, there is little practical difference - the main difference, in my opinion, is that using individual, hard-coded attributes is slightly easier with objects (no need to quote the name) while dicts easily allow treating all values as one collection (e.g. summing them). This is why I'd go for objects, since the data of the population objects is likely heterogenous and relatively independent.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should consider using a `namedtuple` (see the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) on the `collections` module). You get to access the attributes of the `Population` object by name like you would with a normal class, e.g. `population.attribute_name` instead of `population['attribute_name']` for a dictionary. Since you're not putting any methods on the `Population` class this is all you need.

For your "saving data" criterion, there's also an `_asdict` method which returns a dictionary of field names to values that you could pass to json. (You might need to be careful about exactly what you get back from this method depending on which version of Python you're using. Some versions return a dictionary, and some return an `OrderedDict`. This might not make any difference for your purposes.)

`namedtuples` are also pretty lightweight, so they also work with your 'Running the Simulation' resource requirement. However, I'd echo other people's caution in saying not to worry about that, there's going to be very little difference unless you're doing some serious data-crunching.

Comment: Again, `namedtuple` is immutable and thus propably not usable here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that in every case a Population is a member of a City, and if it's data only, why not use a dictionary?

Don't worry about performance, but if your really need to know I think a dict is faster.