# Python how to organise data instead of nested dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have read quite a few SO posts on nested dictionaries and lists (e.g. [Object vs. Dictionary: how to organise a data tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397246/object-vs-dictionary-how-to-organise-a-data-tree)), but I still don't understand when to choose different data structures.

I often find myself start programming with for example a dictionary of lists, and then oh, I need to add something else, lets make each value in the list a tuple, and then there something else... Soon its a deep frankenstein of nested lists and dicts.

And then I try and spend more time trying to document the data structure with comments, then actually coding it. I also still think it's hard for the next programmer to pick up and use. Seems like I just make everything complicated. At which point I think about making classes to handle it. Classes with just attributes seems none ideal.

Here is a basic example:

```
dict = {
    heading1 : [
        (value1, id1), (value2, id2)
    ],
    heading2 : [
        (value3, id3), (value4, id4)
    ],
}
```

How can one code the above data structure to be more easily understood and maintainable?

Comment: You need classes - their attributes can be of any type you want, including nested dictionaries or lists. Attributes could be instances of other custom classes too. Much easier than the dictionary you have where the values are lists of tuples.

Comment: General design questions like this are not really appropriate for [so]. It's closer to the subject matter of [softwareengineering.se], but you'd probably have to ask more specific questions about why one design is better than another, rather than broad recommendations.

Comment: @run_the_race, let me introduce you to [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), your new best friend.

Comment: I had learnt about named tuples now, and they are great for code readilbility. However, the downside with them is searching through a list of them. E.g. a list of named tuples and trying to find the tuples whose column is a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

Your complex dictionary containing lists of tuples can be replaced by objects.

```
dict = {
    heading1 : [
        (value1, id1), (value2, id2)
    ],
    heading2 : [
        (value3, id3), (value4, id4)
    ],
}
```

Instead, you can try the following. It’s not a great example, but gives an idea of how it might work.

```
class Thing:
    headings = [] # This will be a list of Headings

class Heading:
    values = [] # This will be a list of values, of whatever type you need (e.g. string)
```

Use it like this:

```
heading = Heading()
heading.values.append("Test value")

thing = Thing()
thing.headings.append(heading)

print(thing.headings[0].values[0]) # Prints "Test value"
```